# Range of $T$ and of $TT^t$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

We are working in a Hilbert space and $\cdot ^t$ denotes the Hilbert space transpose.

> Is it always true that $\operatorname{ran}T=\operatorname{ran}TT^t$?

In finite dimensions one can use that $\operatorname{ran}T=(\ker T^t)^\perp$. The proof of the above could work unchanged if $\operatorname{ran}T$ was assumed to be closed, but this is not the case.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "transpose" here. If $T$ is multiplication by the identity function on $L^2[0,1]$, is the identity function in the range of $T^2$? What about multiplication by $\frac{1}{n}$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$? Those are the kinds of places I would be looking for counterexamples.